# Error parsing from .csv to mysql using Spring boot batch

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to dump data from a **.csv file to a mysql database using Spring Boot Batch.** My config code is-

```
@Configuration //this is important- enables batch processing in the project
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<User> reader(){
        FlatFileItemReader<User> reader=new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("records2.csv"));
        reader.setLineMapper(getLineMapper()); //how to map the line which is read.
        reader.setLinesToSkip(1); // skip lines when error occurs
        return reader;
    }
    private LineMapper<User> getLineMapper() {
        DefaultLineMapper<User> lineMapper=new DefaultLineMapper<>();
        DelimitedLineTokenizer delimitedLineTokenizer=new DelimitedLineTokenizer();

        delimitedLineTokenizer.setNames(new String[]{"Roll Number","Name of Student","Personal Email ID","College Email ID","MOBILE NO"});
        delimitedLineTokenizer.setIncludedFields(new int[]{1,2,3,4,5});

        BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<User> fieldSetMapper=new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
        fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(User.class);
        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(delimitedLineTokenizer);
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);

        return lineMapper;
    }
    @Bean
    public UserItemProcessor processor(){
        return new UserItemProcessor();
    }
    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<User> writer(){
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<User> writer= new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
        writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<User>());
        writer.setSql("insert into user(rollNo,name,personalEmail,officialEmail,mobileNo) values (:rollNo,:name,:personalEmail,:officalEmail,:mobileNo)");
        writer.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return writer;
    }



    @Bean 
    public Job importUserJob(){

        return jobBuilderFactory.get("USER_IMPORT_JOB")
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .flow(step1())
        .end()
        .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1(){
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("Step 1")
        .<User,User>chunk(5)
        .reader(reader())
        .writer(writer())
        .build();
    }
}
```

When I run the code I am getting the following error in parsing-

```
org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException: Parsing error at line: 2 in resource=[class path resource [records2.csv]], input=[1,User 1,abc20nov@gmail.com,abc@college.com,9171046141]
        at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doRead(FlatFileItemReader.java:189) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.7.jar:4.3.7]
        at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:93) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.7.jar:4.3.7]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:99) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar:4.3.7]
```

As I can understand that  data code not be parsed but cannot understand the reason for it. The contents of the records2.csv are-
[image]
Can somebody explain why this error occurs?

Comment: That error is completely to be expected if you are reading a .xlsx file. You are attempting to read it as if it were a text file, but it is not: it is a binary file. If you want to read the contents of this file, you will need to find a Java library that can read .xlsx files. CSV files however are text files, so I would expect a different error for those. Edit your question to include the error you get for a .csv file, and include the error in your question as text, not as an image.

Comment: I have updated the question. I have problem specific to .csv files.

Comment: @coder001 - Can you please share the content of records2.csv file?

Comment: I have added a sample image please check.